# Search across multiple ExpressionEngine sites using Multisite Manager

Tags: expressionengine

Is there a way to search across multiple channels in multiple sites using the built in EE search tags and Multisite Manager?

I'm not able to find anything in the documentation for the search tags or MSM that would indicate how to do this or even if it is possible.

It's early days but so far I've tried including a site_id or site parameter (as shown below) and also tried specifying site_name:channel_name in the channel parameter but so far no luck.

```
{exp:search:simple_form channel="news|pages" site="site1|site2|site3" result_page="search/results" search_in="everywhere" where="all"}
```

UPDATE: It would seem that as of January 2011 this is not possible using the search tags and requires a custom query. 
http://expressionengine.com/forums/viewthread/178300/

Answer (score 1):

If you have $120 in the budget then Solspace's Super Search module [supports](http://www.solspace.com/docs/detail/super_search_search/#site) MSM searches. Alternatively you could probably put together a [Google custom search](http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=70322&ctx=cb&src=cb&cbid=rjn0hklridhb) without too much trouble.

Comment: I found that I could construct a custom SQL query to do it but discovered Low Search which looks like it will do what I need and is less than half the price of Super Search - I've used that before and although it's ok I wasn't drawn to use it again.